# C# and Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, oop, reflection

I'm a brand-newbie to C#, albeit not programming, so please forgive me if I mix things up a bit -- it's entirely unintentional.  I've written a fairly simple class called "API" that has several public properties (accessors/mutators).  I've also written a testing console application that uses reflection to get an alphabetically list of names & types of each property in the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using MyNamespace;      // Contains the API class

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi");

            API api = new API(1234567890, "ABCDEFGHI");
            Type type = api.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

            // Sort properties alphabetically by name.
            Array.Sort(props, delegate(PropertyInfo p1, PropertyInfo p2) { 
                return p1.Name.CompareTo(p2.Name); 
            });

            // Display a list of property names and types.
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in type.GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} [type = {1}]", propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now what I need is a method that loops through the properties and concats all the values together into a querystring.  The problem is that I'd like to make this a function of the API class itself (if possible).  I'm wondering if static constructors have something to do with solving this problem, but I've only been working with C# for a few days, and haven't been able to figure it out.

Any suggestions, ideas and/or code samples would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is unrelated to `static` constructors. You can do it with [`static` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx):

```
class API {
    public static void PrintAPI() {
       Type type = typeof(API); // You don't need to create any instances.
       // rest of the code goes here.
    }
}
```

You can call it with:

```
API.PrintAPI();
```

You don't use any instances when you call `static` methods.

**Update:** To cache the result, you can either do it on first call or in an `static` initializer:

```
class API {
    private static List<string> apiCache;
    static API() {
        // fill `apiCache` with reflection stuff.
    }

    public static void PrintAPI() {
        // just print stuff from `apiCache`.
    } 
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed -- thank you so much! 

One more question: I came across a previous Stackoverflow question which suggested the following:

 "..when you are reflecting to find all the types that support a certain attribute, 
 you have a perfect opportunity to use caching. That means you don't have to use 
 reflection more than once at runtime."
 

This seems to describe what I want to do, but I don't know what changes I need to make (and where) to only do this at load time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: AspNyc, to create a cache all you have to do is store the results of the PrintApi method that Mehrdad described into a collection such as ArrayList or the generic version List<>. Where you store or persist the collection or cache is up to you. It could be inside the object you queried or the client code that initiated the query.